# Get column value for row where other column values match across rows (matching parent values)

Tags: python, pandas

Can't seem to find this listed anywhere else. I have a df like so:

```
A ID | A Parent ID | B ID | B Parent ID
1    | NA          | 11   | NA
2    | 1           | 12   | 11
3    | NA          | 13   | 11
4    | 2           | 14   | 12
5    | 2           | 15   | 12
6    | NA          | 16   | 12
7    | NA          | 17   | 13
8    | 3           | 18   | 13
9    | 6           | 19   | 16
10   | NA          | 20   | 17
```

What I want to do is, where the column 'B Parent ID' is not null, I want to fill the column 'A Parent ID' with the value from the column 'A ID' that corresponds to the row where 'B ID' equals the original row's 'B Parent ID'. Essentially, I am trying to assign parent IDs for type A based on parent IDs of type B, as I am missing IDs for type A, but not B. So, the desired output would be:

```
A ID | A Parent ID | B ID | B Parent ID
1    | NA          | 11   | NA
2    | 1           | 12   | 11
3    | 1           | 13   | 11
4    | 2           | 14   | 12
5    | 2           | 15   | 12
6    | 2           | 16   | 12
7    | 3           | 17   | 13
8    | 3           | 18   | 13
9    | 6           | 19   | 16
10   | 7           | 20   | 17
```

I have tried using .loc, np.where, and .map, but I cannot figure this out. The df contains around 140k rows, so iterating through the entire df did not work well either.

Comment: From where the value `7` in `A Parent ID` comes from?

Comment: @AndrejKesely in the last row, the value `7` in `A Parent ID` is the value from `A ID` from the row where `B ID` equals the last row in `B Parent ID`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result you want by merging your dataframe with itself on a match between the `B Parent ID` and the `B ID` columns, then selecting `A ID` from the merged result:

```
df['A Parent ID'] = df.merge(df, left_on='B Parent ID', right_on='B ID', how='left')['A ID_y']
```

Output:

```
   A ID  A Parent ID  B ID  B Parent ID
0     1          NaN    11          NaN
1     2          1.0    12         11.0
2     3          1.0    13         11.0
3     4          2.0    14         12.0
4     5          2.0    15         12.0
5     6          2.0    16         12.0
6     7          3.0    17         13.0
7     8          3.0    18         13.0
8     9          6.0    19         16.0
9    10          7.0    20         17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
mask = df["B Parent ID"].notna() & df["A Parent ID"].isna()
df_b_id = df.set_index("B ID")

df.loc[mask, "A Parent ID"] = df.loc[mask, "B Parent ID"].apply(
    lambda x: df_b_id.loc[x, "A ID"]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A ID  A Parent ID  B ID  B Parent ID
0     1          NaN    11          NaN
1     2          1.0    12         11.0
2     3          1.0    13         11.0
3     4          2.0    14         12.0
4     5          2.0    15         12.0
5     6          2.0    16         12.0
6     7          3.0    17         13.0
7     8          3.0    18         13.0
8     9          6.0    19         16.0
9    10          7.0    20         17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map with a pd.Series is more efficient that pandas DataFrame merging:

```
mapper = df.set_index('B ID')['A ID']   
df['A Parent ID'] = df['B Parent ID'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   A ID  A Parent ID  B ID  B Parent ID
0     1          NaN    11          NaN
1     2          1.0    12         11.0
2     3          1.0    13         11.0
3     4          2.0    14         12.0
4     5          2.0    15         12.0
5     6          2.0    16         12.0
6     7          3.0    17         13.0
7     8          3.0    18         13.0
8     9          6.0    19         16.0
9    10          7.0    20         17.0
```

I find when you have a join/merge on one column and your returning one column, then you can always re-write using pd.Series.map with a pd.Series as the mapper.

Create a pd.Series with the value you are joining on in the index and the value of that series is the return value.